# UIView contentstretch changes circle to oval, not to pill shape

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a circle image 80 units by 80 units and was trying to use the contentstretch property of the UIImageView to change it into a pill shape, but I can only get an oval.  Any ideas?  Here is my code:

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,80,80);
imageView.layer.contents = (id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"]).CGImage;
imageView.contentStretch = CGRectMake(0.5, 0,0, 1);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
animations:^{
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x,imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width+50, imageView.frame.size.height);
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){

                             }];
```

Comment: Strange. Your code works properly when I tried it assuming you wanted a rectangle in the middle. Are there any other image view settings that you've altered. I was using it straight out of IB.

Comment: i just tried again with a brand new image view.  i don't set anything else.  it just turns into an oval.

Comment: You can check [`this`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/CircleStretch.zip) out.

Comment: thx for working it out.  it was maybe my image size not being exactly 80px that caused the issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
UIImage *circleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"];
UIImage *stretchImage = [circleImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:40 topCapHeight:40];
imageView.image = stretchImage;
```